# Social button's links issue

Tags: facebook-like, google-plus

I have added on my web-sire some social buttons. Tweet share button works just fine but I have some issues with facebook and google+ button.

In fact I added this away the buttons : (the buttons are supposed to link to a web page through a parameter $URL

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" href="{$URL}"></div>

and for facebook   

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={$URL}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light" allowtransparency="true" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 90px; height: 21px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

In fact I used iframe because my buttons are wrapped by divs that displays them in grey and color them the expected way on hovering.

The problem I have is that when clicking on the g+ no box appears, and when I click again, the g+ button displays a red triangle instead and I have a "+1 button errors" message : but I am in none of the case that would explain this kind of message.

When clicking on the facebook-like, I have nothing displayed on my facebook's wall...

Does anybody has an idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

For the +1 button, I have a few things you can try. Is the actual button itself rendering also or are you getting unexpected behavior when you click it?

If the button isn't rendering, you might be missing the JavaScript library for Google+.  The following code should be added to your post before the actual button gets rendered:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>`

If you are getting unexpected behavior when the button is clicked, you probably are having an issue with the URL parameter. You might be able to get by without passing a URL because the +1 button defaults to the current page. The following example shows the simplest case of rendering the +1 button for the current page:

`<g:plusone></g:plusone>`

If that correctly renders, you are putting something bad into the URL parameter or have something wrong with the strings in your parameters. For example, check that the strings you're using don't have backticks in the starting or closing quotes as opposed to single quotes.

The +1 documentation will have any additional details that you will need for configuring and customizing the button and its parameters.  You can find it here:

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

Comment: The button is rendering correctly. By the way, I even removed the data-href spec, and it still doesn't work. I really don't understand

Comment: Did you try the `<g:plusone>` syntax as opposed to the `<div ...` syntax?  Sometimes this can eliminate some variables in the +1 code.